# When last a table column was modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to know when a user updates a table column? For example, at what time a user changes their last name?

Im not interested when last a table was updated; only the column. Is it possible using Rails 5 and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are including timestamps in your models (`.created_at` and `.updated_at`) then `.updated_at` will tell you the last time that the record (i.e. the database row) was updated.

But that will not tell you which attribute of the record was changed (i.e. which database column).  Nor will it tell you which user changed it, or if it was changed automatically by something in your system, etc.

Comment: I have updated_at etc on my table. I need to know when an attribute was last updated. I really thought this was possible. Ex (not possible, I know): `User.first.last_name.updated_at`

Comment: Nope, you need to use the papertrail gem or something similar for that level of granularity.

Comment: Good stuff. I'll check that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need the schema to do that. You can a new table called as user_logs and implement a trigger which stores old_record and new_record. This will help you to get the desired log for change.